# My friend pointed out [It is inappropriate to throws at main]. How and where should I fix it?

Tags: java

Should I add a method and do not call throws in main? 
Is that appropriate? 
How do I write it? I do not know how to write.

```
 private static String fileName = "C:\\fruit.csv"; 
public static void main(String[] args) throws 
IOException{
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
FileReader(fileName));
 TreeMap<String,Integer> tm = new 
TreeMap<String,Integer>();
    String line;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Sample");
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    try{
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] words = line.split("\\s");
            for(String s : words){
                if(!tm.containsKey(s)){
                    tm.put(s,1);
                    logger.debug(s+""+tm.get(s)+"N");}else{
                    tm.put(s,tm.get(s).intValue()+1);
                    logger.debug(s+""+tm.get(s)+"N");}}}
        }catch(IOException e){
        logger.debug("Error");
        }finally{ br.close()}
        Writer fw = new FileWriter("C:\\count.properties");
        Properties p =new Properties();
        for(String key : tm.keySet()){
            p.setProperty(key,String.valueOf(tm.get(key)));
        }p.store(fw,"fruit");}}}
```

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` extends `IOException`, so maybe just wrap it all up in that try block

Comment: im sorry. It was an IO Exception, not a FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it inappropriate? Who says it is?

It entirely depends on the program, so broadly claiming that "it is inappropriate to throws at main" is wrong<sup>1</sup>.

What do you think should happen if an exception occurs? It is *your* decision to make, and the decision likely depends heavily on the purpose of the program.

It *is* an **exception**, so you likely want it printed, with a stacktrace so you can figure out where and why. Which is exactly what the `java` command does when `main` throws an exception, so why should you catch it, just to do the very same thing yourself?

Sure, if it is a command-line utility program, you'd likely want to catch the exception (including `RuntimeException` and `Error`), to print a one-line error message, without stacktrace, and then end the program with an exit code. But not all java programs are command-line utility programs.

<sup>1) Anyway, that is *my* opinion on the topic.</sup>

Comment: If an error occurs, I want to output to the log at debug level.  Anyway, please write and tell me how to not write throw in main.  I want to think while comparing from the answer.  I do not know how to write other than main.

Comment: If you want to *log* the exception, then you will of course have to `catch` the exception, and since you won't be re-throwing it, that means you don't need to declare `throws` for the `main` method. I'm unsure what you're asking. Don't you know how to `catch` an exception?